# How can i have multiple loop to reach list of all files from multiple determined folders?

Tags: python

I have multiple folders. I will read some of them; each folder includes various files (images) that I want access to their paths. I used the below code:

```
[os.path.join(folder,fname) for fname in os.listdir(folder) for folder in selected_train]
```

previously I had a list of folders in folders.
but I get the below error:

```
name 'folder' is not defined
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: you have a `.` after `in` idk if that is your issue but maybe you should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typing mistake.

Comment: Perhaps use `os.walk` instead?

Comment: @EliHarold yah i need speed of that

Comment: @S3DEV could you please clarify your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk` function to navigate through the folder.

```
import os

subfiles=[x[2] for x in os.walk(".")]
print(subfiles)
```

And also, if you want to just one list you can do this;

```
import os
subfiles=[]
for x in os.walk("."):
        subfiles.extend(x[2])#x[2] represent the all files in one directory
print(subfiles)
```

Comment: You already have all files in `files` variable, why do you call `os.listdir()`? Iterate over `files` and join filename to root path using `os.path.join(root, file)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes you're right, I edited.

Comment: By using this, finally i have a list of list (of my paths) but i want just one list.

Comment: @shivaparsarad, this code if far from perfect though. Use `[os.path.join(folder, file) for folder, _, files in os.walk(".") for file in files]`.

Comment: @shivaparsarad Okay, i edited my answer according both of your recommendations.

Comment: @OlvinRoght this idea is not speeding effiecient.

Comment: @shivaparsarad, I have not said that it's efficient, it just does what you need with method from this answer.